# node:events:491 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm

I install the packages fine. Now I try and compile the scripts with `npm run dev` like thus..

**terminal**

```
npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:285:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:483:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--hide-modules',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v19.2.0
```

**terminal**

```
npm -v
8.19.3
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
}
```

If you can help me with;-

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Any news about how to solve this one?